# the $\int_1^\infty (logx)^p x^k dx $ is convergence?

Tags: analysis

> Consider the $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty (logx)^p x^k  dx$. by what condition on $p$ and $k$ the integral is convergence?

my work:
i use $logx=r$.

but i can not solve the problem.

Comment: At infinity, since $\log x$ compare to $x$ is too tiny at infinity, it is almost equivalent to throw $\log x$ away. At 1, you simply throw $x^k$ away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify things, do this transformation
$$ \int_1^\infty (\log(x))^p x^k \, dx = \int_0^\infty x^p (e^x)^k e^x\,dx = \int_0^\infty x^p e^{(k+1)x}\,dx.$$

For this to integrate at 0, you must have $p > -1.$  For the exponential to decay at $\infty$, you must have $k < -1$.  Suppose these hold. Then
$$\int_0^\infty x^p e^{-|1+k|x}\,dx = \int_0^\infty \left({x^p\over|1+k|^p}\right)e^{-x}{dx\over |1+k|} = {1\over|1+k|^{p+1}}\int_0^\infty x^p e^{-x}\,dx = {\Gamma(p+1)\over|1+k|^{p+1}} $$

Comment: Under the tacit assumption that p  and k  are real, and satisfy p>−1  and k<−1 , then one needs to replace k+1  with |k+1|  in the last line of equalities.  I hope that you don't mind my having made the edits.

Comment: Thanks  for your good work.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And nice solution.